# add content other than attribute information under "Additional information" in magento

Tags: tabs, additional-information

we can see "Additional information " tab in magento product view page.

there we can list all attributes.

I want to display some contents under "Additional information " tab....

means

Main information

attribute label 1 : attribute value

Sub - information

attribute label 2 : atribute value.

please let me know if you need any clarifications.

thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Is this a static block or a custom template that will contain product data?

Comment: no, it's not a static block, seems custom template only....

Comment: Was the answer useful? http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could customize the template `catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`. Copy it to your theme from `base/default` if it isn't there yet and include what you need.

For better maintainability, I'd recommend to just add `$this->getChildHtml('my_child_alias')` to the template and define child blocks in the layout (i.e. `layout/local.xml` of your theme:

```
<reference name="product.attributes">
    <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.product.block" as="my_child_alias" template="my/custom/template.phtml" />
</reference>
```